# Is it possible to run protractor tests in more than one browser language?

Tags: protractor

I need to run protractor tests in more than one browser language.
Can this be set up in the args value under chrome options?

```
Node Version: v8.9.0
Protractor Version: 5.2.0
Browser(s): Chrome
My config file:

exports.config = { 
    framework: 'jasmine', 
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', 
    capabilities: { 
         browserName: 'chrome', 
         chromeOptions: { 
              //i'd like to config >1 lang here if possible
              args: ['lang=en-AU', 'lang=ja-JP'],
              prefs: { accept_languages: ['en-AU','ja-JP'] }
              }, 
         suites: { 
              home: './home/home.spec.js' 
              } 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple Chrome profiles and then select, with which profile you want to launch the browser.

In the profile you specify the language.
I guess, that's the best way, as the language option itself seems not exposed.

Alternatively, change the regional settings of your OS, as most probably that language is selected, if no other language is specified in the profile.

Comment: Hi Ernst, thanks for your time. This solution didn't work for me as i was not able to determine the browser language within the spec. ended up created a separate json file containing the culture/language and passing this into the protractor.conf. This means I can pass the culture to the spec also, and so verify ui language is correct.